# while deleting the particular items from iteration of items in click event first item is deleting instead of clciked one

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, for-loop, foreach

In my angular application I have some iteration items and saving the items based on adding the items.
**.component.html**

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let categoryDetail of selectedCategoryDetails">
      <div class="__header">
        <div>
          <b>{{ categoryDetail.category }}</b>
        </div>
         </div>

      <div
        class="clinical-note__category__details"
        *ngIf="categoryDetail.showDetails">
      
        <ul>
          <li class="habit-list"
            *ngFor="let habits of categoryDetail.habitDetails" >
        
            <div class="target-details">
              <b>{{ clinicalNoteLabels.target }}: </b
              ><span class="habit-list__value">{{ habits.target }}</span>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="habit-footer">
       <span class="m-l-10"  
          [popoverOnHover]="false"
          type="button"
          [popover]="customHabitPopovers"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" ></i> Delete</span>
        </div>
        <div class="clinical-note__popoverdelete">

        <popover-content #customHabitPopovers [closeOnClickOutside]="true">
          <h5>Do you want to delete this habit?</h5>
          <button
          class="btn-primary clinical-note__save"  (click)="deletedata(index);customHabitPopovers.hide()">yes </button>
       
        </popover-content></div>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
```

**.component.ts**

```
public saveHealthyHabits() {
    let isCategoryExist = false;
    let categoryDetails = {
      category: this.clinicalNoteForm.controls.category.value,
      habitDetails: this.healthyHabits.value,
      showDetails: true,
    };
    if (this.customHabitList.length) {
      categoryDetails.habitDetails = categoryDetails.habitDetails.concat(
        this.customHabitList
      );
      this.customHabitList = [];
    }

    if (this.selectedCategoryDetails) {
      this.selectedCategoryDetails.forEach((selectedCategory) => {
        if (selectedCategory.category === categoryDetails.category) {
          isCategoryExist = true;
          selectedCategory.habitDetails = selectedCategory.habitDetails.concat(
            categoryDetails.habitDetails
          );
        }
      });
    }
    if (!this.selectedCategoryDetails || !isCategoryExist) {
      this.selectedCategoryDetails.push(categoryDetails);
    }

    this.clinicalNoteForm.patchValue({
      category: null,
    });
    this.healthyHabits.clear();
  }
public deletedata(index:number){

   if (this.selectedCategoryDetails) {
    this.selectedCategoryDetails.forEach((selectedCategory) => {
    this.selectedCategoryDetails.splice(index, 1);
   }}
```

From the above code I have saved the data based on adding the items as above and my requirement is when we click on the delete(it will show the popup having the button yes implemented in anbove code).

when we click on the yes button  from list of items, I have to remove the particular item
When I tried removing ,It is only deleting the first item instead of clicked one
Can anyone help me on the same

Comment: Please add complete code. The logic of `deletedata` is missing.

Comment: @random I have edited the code for deletedata

Answer (score 0):

The logic for `deletion` is incorrect. The `splice` mutates the original array, and you are applying the loop for deletion, which keeps on iterating over the array and deleting the array elements based on index, instead of deleting single matched index element.

**Example -**

```js
const categories = [
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4
];

function removal(i) {
  categories.forEach((category, index) => {
    categories.splice(i, 1);
  });
  console.log('----Categories-->', categories);
}

removal(0);
```

|  | Categories Array |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First Iteration [index = 0] | [1,2,3,4] | Loop Starts Iterating from 1 |
| Second Iteration [index = 1] | [2,3,4] | Loop Starts Iterating from 3 |
| Third Iteration [index = 2] | [3,4] | Stop |

Instead you can use `filter` function.

```
public deletedata(index:number){
  this.selectedCategoryDetails = this.selectedCategoryDetails.filter((_, i) => i! == index);
}
```

*Note - I would recommend to delete the categories based on some identifier like `id` instead of `index` because the array elements position can get changed.*

Instead of passing `index` to `deleteData` method, you can pass the `category` object.

```
 public deletedata(category){
  this.selectedCategoryDetails = this.selectedCategoryDetails.filter((c) => c.id! == category.id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks@random, but for the above method for deletedata when I clcik on the button it is removing all the items instead of selected one, could you please help me on this

Comment: @user1 - As i mentioned your deletion logic is incorrect. Replace your `deletion` logic with `filter`.

Comment: even if I use the above code it is removing entire items not clicked one I stucked in this could you please edit the above code in both html and css then it would be more helpful for me

Comment: @user1 - Please create the working fiddle.

Comment: I am unable to create with this code ,as per the above code when I click on delete button it will show the confirmation popup(implemented) having some text and yes button , So when I click on yes button it has to remove the particular item from the iteration, Could you help me by adding the code it would be helpful for me